# RTK query returned data reset in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, rtk-query

I am using rtk query to search for guests as user types names.
if you type "t" it ll give you all guests whose name contains "t".
And when you click on the name on that list you select that guest.

Now when I select a guest from that list, I need to reset the data returned from the rtkquery to an empty array or undefined. But since the returned data is const i can not just it to undefined so it clears the list of names.

1. So my question is how do you clear the data returned from a query.(I am not talking about cache)
2. Or should I use "useState" in that component and copy the returned data from the query and use the copied state. (which also causes re renders) .

I mean a dirty hack would be hiding the section where I render the list with a boolean and set it false when a select a user from the list but I rather reset the rendering data.

```
const [searchGuests, { data: guests,isLoading }] = useLazySearchGuestQuery();


{guests.map(each => (
  <div key={each.id}>
    <div  onClick={() => selectItem(each)}>
      {each.first_name} + {each.last_name} 
        <div>
        {each.phone} {each.email} 
        </div>
   </div>
 </div> ))}
```

So how can I clear `guest` so that list is not rendered.